# unix find on aix with a certain depth

Tags: unix, aix

I want to find directories on a filesystem but ignore directories that are deeper in the tree.

For example this is my tree:

```
abc
 - dir1
     - parti
 - dir2
     - parti
     - dir2a
          -parti
     - dir2b
          -parti
          -dirxxx
     - dir2c
          -dirxxx
 - dir3
     - parti
 - dir4
     - parti
     - dir4a
          -parti
     - dir4b
          -parti
```

Now the result I need is only the parti directories just after the first dir and not deeper in the tree.

So the result should be

```
./dir1/parti
./dir2/parti
./dir3/parti
./dir4/parti
```

If I use a normal find commando:

```
find . -type d -name 'parti'
```

I get as result also the parti dirs at a deeper level.
How can I ignore these ?